# Google BigQuery :How to Generate Date Array by End of Month date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to generate dates by End of Month

```
SELECT
Date_Ranges
FROM 
    UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-01-31', DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), MONTH),
 INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL 1 Month)) AS Date_Ranges
```

But the Result I get is:

| Date_Ranges |
| --- |
| 31/01/2020 |
| 29/02/2020 |
| 29/03/2020 |
| 29/04/2020 |
| 29/05/2020 |
| 29/06/2020 |
| 29/07/2020 |
| 29/08/2020 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll probably be easier to break your logic up.  Something like this seems to work:

```
select date_sub(BOMs, interval 1 day) as EOM
from unnest(generate_date_array('2020-01-01', current_date(), interval 1 month)) BOMs
```

You can change the first 2 arguments in the `generate_date_array` function to get the specific window you want.

Answer (score 6):

Another option:

```
select last_day(dt, month) Date_Ranges
from unnest(generate_date_array('2020-01-01', current_date(), interval 1 month)) dt
```